# Excel Statement with 4 conditions and 4 answers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

All of the methods that I've used have 2 answer values (True or False).

How can I get the following with a formula?

- If A1=1 then it's 11, if A1=2 the answer is 22, if A1=3 then it's 33, if A1=4 it's 44.

Comment: You can use nested IF's, or CHOOSE perhaps.

Comment: @BigBen Post as an answer?

Comment: What about `=A1*11`

Answer (score 1):

If the value your are evaluating is in cell A1, then the nested function would be as follows:

```
IF(A1=1,11,IF(A1=2,22,IF(A1=3,33,IF(A1=4,44,""))))
```

I put the 2 double commas at the end so the formula returns a blank instead of false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you are asking about, but you can make multiple (nested) IF statements in one. For example:

IF(1=2;TRUE;IF(2=2;TRUE;FALSE))

You just put another IF in the FALSE part of IF statement. If that's not it, can you give a piece of the statement you tried and precise more what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(INT(A1)=A1,A1<=4,A1>=1),A1*11,"")
```

Now the above works for the condition you placed in your example, however if one were to go by your title alone you have a couple of options you could go with.

You first Option would be nested IF statements.  Like you said each IF function has TRUE or FALSE.  The trick is to put another IF function in for the TRUE result and another in for the FALSE results

```
IF(CHECK1, IF(CHECK2, TRUE2, FALSE2),IF(CHECK3, TRUE3, FALSE3))
```

The above give 4 potential results based on only 3 checks.  Another option would be to do a check and supply a value for a TRUE result and another IF for a false result.  Keep repeating the process.  Conversely you could go the same route flipping TRUE FALSE option.  It might look something like this:

```
IF(CHECK1, TRUE1, IF(CHECK2, TRUE2, IF(CHECK3, TRUE3, FALSE3)))
```

FALSE3 would be the result of all previous checks failing.

So for your case, your nested IF could look like (assuming the only valid entries are 1, 2, 3 and 4):

```
IF(A1=1,11,IF(A1,2,22,IF(A1=3,33,44)))

OR

IF(ISODD(A1),IF(A1=1,11,33),IF(A1=2,22,44))
```

and there are other options to work through the logic.  there are also other checks you could be doing and results being displayed if your entries in A1 were not limited to the integers 1,2,3 and 4.

Now because you example is using the sequential integers 1,2,3 and 4 you could also use the CHOOSE function.  Alternatively if you can make your criteria evaluate to sequential integers stating at 1 the CHOOSE function would work as well.  Supply choose with an integer as the first argument and it will return the corresponding argument in the list that follows

```
CHOOSE(ARGUMENT,RESULT1, RESULT2,...,RESULTn-1, RESULTn)
```

In your case it would look something like:

```
CHOOSE(A1,11,22,33,44)
```

If you can not get sequential numbers for whatever reason and the gap is numbers is small and you are in the low integer count, you could leave a gap in results by providing "", or 0).  lets say you has 1,3 and 4 as potential arguments, then your choose might look like:

```
CHOOSE(A1,11,"",33,44)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1<>"",INDEX({11;22;33;44},A1),"")

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1<=4),A1*11,"")
```